# Using WMIC to find version then run respective actions

Tags: wmic

I want to run a batch to find out which version of Symantec End Point in order to perform update or upgrade actions.
I got error when implementing below script - No Instance(s) available
Please help to review how to correct it.

```
set latestVersion=14.3.5427.3000
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims== " %%i in ('wmic product where "Name like 'Symantec End 
Point'" get version /format:Textvaluelist') do set currentversion=%%i

echo %currentversion%
Pause
if %currentVersion%==%latestVersion% goto update
if %currentVersion% GEQ %latestVersion% goto update
if %currentVersion% LEQ %latestVersion% goto upgrade
```

Comment: Your query is fine.  Your product name must not be (I do not have Symantec installed).  I am able to switch out `Symantec End Point` with something I have on my machine and the query works and returns results in the `currentversion` variable.  Run `wmic product`.. scrape the screen to get your product name.

Comment: I need to modify the script to make it works :  for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims== " %%i in ('wmic Product where name^=^"Symantec Endpoint Protection^" get version /format:Textvaluelist') do set currentversion=%%i

Comment: Is there any way that I can combine these two conditions into one one line ?                     if %currentVersion%==%latestVersion% goto update
if %currentVersion% GEQ %latestVersion% goto update

Comment: First, I didn't add escapes to the quotes and it worked fine on my machine.. but whatever.  Second, 14.3.5427.3000 isn't a number and therefore I don't expect that you will have luck with GEQ and LEQ.  Regardless, you should quote both sides so if %currentVersion% is empty, it doesn't throw an error.